# Unable to complete multipart upload to s3 using aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, multipart-upload

createmultipartupload is working fine and upload through signed urls is also working fine. once i reach to completeMultipartUpload it says NoSuchUpload: The specified upload does not exist. The upload ID may be invalid, or the upload may have been aborted or completed.
Although all the parts have been successfully uploaded to s3

Comment: Can you include a [mre] to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: For others who are running into the same error, it is not always your UploadId. This error can be a result of a Key mismatch between the params of your s3.createMultipartUpload, and s3.getSignedUrl, and s3.completeMultipartUpload. Make sure your Keys are the same across all 3 s3 calls.

Comment: @Leonard yep that was also it for me